# 301 redirect www.root.com/subfolder to www.subfolder.com on same server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi people at Stackoverflow,

I've honestly searched here and tried stuff but since I'm really not an expert and nothing worked, I'm lost and need your help. I don't post here often because usually I find what I am looking for.

### The situation

I have different sites running on the same server. Let's say that one of my websites is called Cats. It runs with CMSMS and resides in a subfolder of my root called `cats.com`.

In the root of my server there is a htaccess file with this code (generated by the server admin):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www.cats.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/cats.com/
RewriteRule (.*)            /cats.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^cats.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/cats.com/
RewriteRule (.*)            /cats.com/$1
```

In the cats.com subfolder there is a htaccess file with rewrite code for pretty urls:

```
# RewriteBase /cats.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

This works. When I request www.cats.com I see the contents of the /cats.com subfolder in my root but the URL base stays www.cats.com and all the URLS are extremely pretty.

However, due to a setup error (my bad) in my site's config file, the URL listed in Google is

```
http://www.root.com/cats.com
```

When I click the URL, I see the correct page but the address bar reads `http://www.root.com/cats.com`. The pretty URL rewrite works, but I want this url to rewrite to `www.cats.com`.

### What I have tried

I have tried rewriting the Google listed URL with

#### attempt one

I tried this in both htaccess files, below and above the existing rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^/cats.com(.*)$ http://www.cats.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/cats.com/(.*)$ http://www.cats.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Nothing happens. Everything stays the same.

#### attempt two

Again tried this in both htaccess files, below and above existing rewrite rules

```
Redirect 301 /cats.com http://cats.com
```

This results in an infinite loop in all occasions.

---

I hope my description is clear enough...

If anybody has any idea what might / should work I'd love to hear it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rules in `cats.com` subfolder's `htaccess` file to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cats.com/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+(cats\.com)/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It does in a way, but it results in a 404 error from the root site. The URL reads www.root.com/cats.com Root redirects to a subfolder called dogs.com Could it be that the redirect now tries to find root/dogs.com/cats.com? (does this make any sense?)

Comment: Oops, I just realised I made a typo in your code when I replaced the urls... (sorry!) It redirects differently now but but unfortunately not the way it should. When I request www.root.com/cats.com/file.html it redirects to root.com/file.html and I get a 404 error. It should redirect to cats.com/file.html (Is it important to mention that the root redirects to a different subfolder dogs.com?)

Comment: It didn't at first but I un-escaped the dots in the RewriteBase and THE_REQUEST and now it does! You are my hero, I could never have figured this out. Thank you so much!